# Python and setting arguments

Tags: python

I've been recently introduced to Python and asked to run a program and document the results. However, I've been presented with an error.
May someone explain how I should set a role and a host?

error: the following arguments are required: role, host

[image: http://i.imgur.com/WZ4wkol.png]

From what I understand, an argument is usually passed from me to the program.
This rookie appreciates all help! Thank you.

Comment: Always post as much as you can here; not on other sites. If the other site goes down, or the link breaks, you question because useless to future users. Plus, pictures can't be indexed that we'll, so this won't be as searchable. Also, post the code. It's extremely hard of not impossible to diagnose a compiler error without the code.

Comment: With absolutely no information, it's hard to do more than guess, but my first guess is that you're supposed to be running it with command-line arguments, maybe `python foo.py my-role my-host` or `python foo.py --role=my-role --host=my-host` or similar, and you're just doing `python foo.py`.

Comment: Now that we can see that there's a standard usage message… this doesn't seem to be a Python problem, or even a programming problem; it's just learning how to use typical Unix command-line tools. So, I don't think this belongs on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how the python file works, we cannot tell you how to use it, but
it actually tells you in the error message already quite a bit. It looks like you should run something like:

```
python tcp_deadlock.py {server,client} 123.123.123.123
```

where you use a hostname (to connect to?) instead of 123.123.123.123.